# Reading and Updating application settings from NSUserDefaults using Flipside View Controller

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, nsuserdefaults

Does any one have a good sample to read and update application settings from NSUserDefaults using a flipside view controller.

I'd like to read and edit 4 fields stored in textbox, pickerview and a slider control. Any sample code would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

[NSUserDefaults reference](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is the enlightenment that you seek.

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna check out [InAppSettingsKit](http://www.inappsettingskit.com). It doesn't currently offer a picker but can be extended for it.